# vb.net code to copy a pdf file from one folder to another and save path in database and retrieve it later

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am using vb.net and access 2007. I want to save the pdf file path in a databese and want to retrieve the path and read the pdf file when click the button or image.

I have a form where i browse and give the path of the pdf file, when i click on save button the path in the textbox should be read and the pdf file should be copied somewhere in the project folders and the path should be saved in the database.
When i want to retrieve the datails i should get the pdf file along with other details and when i click on the button or image i shoud be able to read the pdf file as in pdf format only ,not in text boxes..
This is the code i am trying to copy the file from one location to other and save the path in database.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    ' Specify the directories you want to manipulate.
    Dim path As String = txtSLAPath.Text
    Dim path2 As String = "E:\" + "SLA1.pdf"
    Try
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path, 1024)
        fs.Close()

        'Copy the file.
        File.Copy(path, path2)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        Dim insQry As String
        insQry = "insert into SLAdb (PO,SLA)values(@PO,@SLA)"

        cnnOLEDB.Open()

        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(insQry, cnnOLEDB)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@PO", txtPO.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@SLA", path2))

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Data Saved Successfully")

        cnnOLEDB.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

file is copied and path is saves but please suggest me to read the path and file.

Answer (score 0):

> Both files become zero bytes

Of course, you create a new file over the same path of the source file without writing anything into.
Then, you close the FileStream and pass the path (of the now zeroed file) to the File.Copy

```
' Specify the directories you want to manipulate.
Dim path As String = txtSLAPath.Text
Dim path2 As String = "E:\" + "SLA1.pdf"
Try

    ' The following line destroy the source file path
    ' the subsequent File.Copy, copies nothing in the destination path

    'Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path, 1024)
    'fs.Close()

    'Copy the file.
    File.Copy(path, path2)

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Thanks.... i found my error and resolved..Thanks for ur help.  But please suggest me for retrieving the pdf file by clicking on a image, whose path has been stored in the database as a pdf file only..as we open any attachment and new window is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You are again `creating a file` by using the `path` and `name` which is same as the source file. i think that might be the problem. Try the following code,

```
 Dim path As String = txtSLAPath.Text
 Dim path2 As String = "E:\" + "SLA1.pdf"
    Try
        'Remove this, but i'm not sure why did you use this here.
        'Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path, 1024)
        'fs.Close()

        'Copy the file.
        File.Copy(path, path2)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Thanks.. yes that was the problem. Actually i was trying with that but latr changed it by below code.. but forgot to comment the previous.

Comment: please suggest me for retrieving the pdf file by clicking on a image, whose path has been stored in the database as a pdf file only..as we open any attachment and new window is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Code to open a file in a new window.

'code to get the file path saved in db..

```
                Dim drPdf As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
                Dim cmd1 As OleDb.OleDbCommand

                Dim pdf As String = ("SELECT * FROM SLAdb where PO='" & txtPo.Text & "'")
                cnnOLEDB.Open()
                cmd1 = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(pdf, cnnOLEDB)
                drPdf = cmd1.ExecuteReader

            If drPdf.Read = True Then
                fpath = drPdf("SLA")
            End If
```

'code to get filename from path

```
                fname = Path.GetFileName(fpath)
                lblSLA.Text = fname
            cnnOLEDB.Close()
```

'code to open the pdf file whose path is saved in db

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fpath)
```